# Compute the pairwise squared difference of multiple vectors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pairwise

I'm looking for the fastest way to calculate the squared difference between two vectors (`(x1-x2)**2`), but pairwise (all combinations or only the upper triangle).

```
x1 = [1,3,5,6,8]
x2 = [3,6,7,9,12]
```

Expected output:

```
array([[   4.,   25.,   36.,   64.,  121.],
       [   0.,    9.,   16.,   36.,   81.],
       [   4.,    1.,    4.,   16.,   49.],
       [   9.,    0.,    1.,    9.,   36.],
       [  25.,    4.,    1.,    1.,   16.]])
```

or

```
array([[   4.,   25.,   36.,   64.,  121.],
       [   0.,    9.,   16.,   36.,   81.],
       [   0.,    0.,    4.,   16.,   49.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    9.,   36.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    16.]])
```

or even (if faster):

```
array([   4.,   25.,   36.,   64.,  121.,    9.,   16.,   36.,   81.,
      4.,    1.,    4.,   16.,   49.,    9.,    1.,    9.,   36.,
     25.,    4.,    1.,    1.,   16.])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and `masking` to get the upper triangular ones and then squaring only those for better performance efficiency -

```
def pairwise_squared_diff(x1, x2):
    x1 = np.asarray(x1)
    x2 = np.asarray(x2)
    diffs = x1[:,None] - x2
    mask = np.arange(len(x1))[:,None] <= np.arange(len(x2))
    return (diffs[mask])**2
```

Sample run -

```
In [85]: x1
Out[85]: array([1, 3, 5, 6, 8])

In [86]: x2
Out[86]: array([ 3,  6,  7,  9, 12])

In [87]: pairwise_squared_diff(x1, x2)
Out[87]: 
array([  4,  25,  36,  64, 121,   9,  16,  36,  81,   4,  16,  49,   9,
        36,  16])
```

#### Possible improvements

**Improvement #1 :**

We could also use `np.tri` to generate `mask` -

```
mask = ~np.tri(len(x1),len(x2),dtype=bool,k=-1)
```

**Improvement #2 :**

If we are okay with a `2D` output with the lower triangular ones set as `0s`, then a simple elementwise multiplication with `mask` solves it too to get the final output -

```
(diffs*mask)**2
```

This would work well with [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) for large data and to gain memory efficiency and hence performance.

**Improvement #3 :**

We could also compute the differences with `numexpr` and hence compute the masked output too with the same `evaulate` method, to give ourselves a new solution altogether -

```
def pairwise_squared_diff_numexpr(x1, x2):
    x1 = np.asarray(x1)
    x2 = np.asarray(x2)
    mask = ~np.tri(len(x1),len(x2),dtype=bool,k=-1)
    return ne.evaluate('mask*((x1D-x2)**2)',{'x1D':x1[:,None]})
```

**Timings with improvements**

Let's study these suggestions on performance for large arrays -

Setup :

```
In [136]: x1 = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000))

In [137]: x2 = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000))
```

With Improvement #1 :

```
In [138]: %timeit np.arange(len(x1))[:,None] <= np.arange(len(x2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 772 µs per loop

In [139]: %timeit ~np.tri(len(x1),len(x2),dtype=bool,k=-1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 243 µs per loop
```

With Improvement #2 :

```
In [140]: import numexpr as ne

In [141]: diffs = x1[:,None] - x2
     ...: mask = np.arange(len(x1))[:,None] <= np.arange(len(x2))

In [142]: %timeit (diffs[mask])**2
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop

In [143]: %timeit ne.evaluate('(diffs*mask)**2')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 ms per loop
```

With Improvement #3 on complete solutions :

```
In [170]: %timeit pairwise_squared_diff(x1, x2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.66 ms per loop

In [171]: %timeit pairwise_squared_diff_numexpr(x1, x2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 ms per loop
```

#### Loopy one

For completeness, here's a loopy one that leverages `slicing` to perform  better than pure `broadcasting` one, owing to the memory-efficiency -

```
def pairwise_squared_diff_loopy(x1,x2):
    n = len(x2)
    idx = np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(n,0,-1).cumsum() ))
    start, stop = idx[:-1], idx[1:]
    L = n*(n+1)//2
    out = np.empty(L,dtype=np.result_type(x1,x2))
    for i,(s0,s1) in enumerate(zip(start,stop)):
        out[s0:s1] = x1[i] - x2[i:]
    return out**2
```

Timings -

```
In [300]: x1 = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000))
     ...: x2 = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000))

In [301]: %timeit pairwise_squared_diff(x1, x2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.44 ms per loop

In [302]: %timeit pairwise_squared_diff_loopy(x1, x2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.73 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is simply perfect =D Thank you again for your great help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcasting:

```
x1 = np.asarray([1,3,5,6,8]).reshape(-1, 1)
x2 = np.asarray([3,6,7,9,12]).reshape(1, -1)
(x1 - x2)**2
```

Output:

```
array([[  4,  25,  36,  64, 121],
       [  0,   9,  16,  36,  81],
       [  4,   1,   4,  16,  49],
       [  9,   0,   1,   9,  36],
       [ 25,   4,   1,   1,  16]])
```

which is simple to code, but computes all values, so it may be optimized to compute only the upper triangle.